# Web sockets & sockets in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm building a server in Node.js. The server uses Websockets with the client and also socket with a second Python server.

```
// Web sockets
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   // Client connected
   // Do some stuff with the client
}

// Sockets
socket.on('data', (msg) => {
   // Python server connected
   // Do some stuff with the Python server
});
```

I would like to run a third callback function when both servers (socket and Websocket) are connected?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure that both client and server are communicating without problems you could make the client emit a message to the server and when the server gets the message it responds with another message to the client. If the client can see this message then the connection has no problem. Here is the code

```
// Client
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   // Client connected
   
   socket.on('server_message',(msg) => {
      print(msg)
   })

   socket.emit('client_message', 'client is connected')
})

// Server
socket.on('client_message', (msg) => {
   socket.emit('server_message', 'server got the message')
})
```

So now if you see on the client console the message "server got the message" then both client and server are communicating without problems.